# WPF Unexepected behaivor of Storyboard.Begin() and Storyboard.SetTarget()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently working on some kind of page indicator control with animation. We designed control like this(not a real code) :

```
<Grid x:Name="main">
    <Grid x:Name="itemStart">
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Ellipse/>
        <TextBlock/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="subGridWhichContainsGridsGeneratedDynamicallyInCodeBehind">
        <Grid x:Name="dummyItemForDesignTimeWhichWillbeRemovedAtConstructor">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Ellipse/>
            <TextBlock/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="itemEnd">
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Ellipse/>
        <TextBlock/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and whenever the page changes, It play Animations:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ellipseAnim">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFD8D8D8"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FFEC4E32"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="#FFEC4E32"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="#FF555555"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="lineAnim">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFD8D8D8"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FFEC4E32"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="#FFEC4E32"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="#FF555555"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="textAnim">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFD8D8D8"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FFEC4E32"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="#FFEC4E32"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="#FF555555"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

like

```
{
  textAnim.Begin(generatedItems[index].InnerTextBlock);
  ///or StoryBoard.SetTarget(textAnim,generatedItems[index].InnerTextBlock); textAnim.Begin();
  ellipseAnim.Begin(generatedItems[index].InnerEllipse);
  lineAnim.Begin(generatedItems[index].InnerRectangleLeft);
  lineAnim.Begin(generatedItems[index].InnerRectangleRight);
}
```

The problem is, it works OK for items which already written in XAML(itemStart and itemEnd). However, when I executes same code for items which are generated by code behind, the animation applies to all of generated items. For example, when I begin the text color change animation(textAnim) for only one generated item's TextBlock, the color of every generated items are changed. Not only TextBlock of every items, but also Rectangles and Ellipses of every items.

I searched a lot but still cannot understand how this is happened. How can I make this to act normal?

Comment: An animation like that will be targeting a specific indexed item. Two possibilities I can think of. Maybe you're using the same brush so when you animate the colour of it then it is the same brush applies to all the items. Or. Your animation is being run for every item rather than just the one you intend it to run for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I guess my case was neither of them... My problem itself was solved when I changed my item generating code from Initializing each element like var grid=new Grid(); grid.Children.Add(... to just XamlReader.Parse(), but I still don't understand how this could solved my problem...

Comment: OK Sorry I was wrong, the problem was with Brush. I wrote the Brush generate method not right so all of them used the same Brush instance as their Fill or Foreground. Thank you for perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, I found the reason of this problem was not with Storyboard. When I assign the color for every element I created, I had to create new Brush for each of them when I create the Item, not `public readonly Brush neutralColorBrush = ...` as global variable and just `Fill = neutralColorBrush`. I was wrong about ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames. It changes the value of Brush which assigned as Fill or Foreground property, not creating new Brush instance by given value and assign them to properties every frames.

Therefore, the reason why this problem was solved with using XamlReader.Parse() to create item was because XamlReader.Parse() creates the new Brush for each Item. If I tried to change it's color with the same way I did after it's created, the problem reproduced.